# на каком слоге ударение в слове творог

Tags: орфоэпия

на каком слоге ударение в слове творог

Comment: Ответ уже был дан. И тв**О**рог, и твор**О**г.

Comment: Предпочтительно - *творОг*.

Comment: @GalinaAvanesova почему?

Comment: Все производные: творОжник, творОжный, створОжиться...  См. также https://www.ekburg.ru/news/18/47663-kak-pravilno-tvorog-ili-tvorog/ + "Русское словесное ударение" на Грамоте.ру.

Comment: @GalinaAvanesova вы какие-то устаревшие пуританские взгляды распространяете))

Comment: Ето я-то?!! 8-(